# What is T.self in Swift5?

Tags: swift

I'm currently going through the Landmarks app tutorial and I'm at the section where you load in JSON into a Struct. They give the following code.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

```
import Foundation


func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {

    let data: Data


    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)

    else {

        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")

    }


    do {

        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)

    } catch {

        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")

    }


    do {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)

    } catch {

        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")

    }

}
```

I specifically don't understand the `T.self` reference nor the `<T: Decodable>` at the beginning of the func. Would someone be able to break the function down? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what `String.self` or `Int.self` or `SomeType.self` means?

Comment: I know that `self` refers to the object itself in question but I'm not entirely clear

Comment: No. `String.self` means String itself, the _type_.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html

Comment: Great, I'll take a look! @Alexander

Comment: So, `decode(T.self)` means that we expect to get a T. It’s a way to pass the name of a type as a parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I see that this question was answered in comments, but I felt it was worth an actual answer for people who are new to Swift trying to understand generics.*

To answer the question, let's look at what `T` is, which is defined in the function's signature

```swift
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T
```

This says that the generic function `load(_:String) -> T` returns some type `T` that conforms to `Decodable`, so `T` is a generic way of referring to the type of the return value, where that type will be determined from the context of the call site, specifically, by the type of whatever is receiving the returned value.

The line being asked about is

```swift
return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
```

Here `T.self` is a way of referring to the type, `T`, itself.   If you look at the function signature for `decode` you'll find it looks something like this:

```swift
func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T
```

Note that it says `T.Type` for the type of the parameter, `type`.  That means that the parameter `type` will hold the type `T` rather than a value of type `T`.  This is Swift's way of differentiating between specifying that a variable is a value of a type vs its value being the type itself.  This can be a little confusing at first, but it makes sense once you get your head around generics.

Because Swift is a strongly typed language, where types are defined at compile-time, `decode` needs to know the type of the thing its attempting to decode.  In a typeless language, like JavaScript or Python, this isn't necessary.  In those languages, objects are basically dictionaries, so it can always decode a dictionary (or an array, or one of a small set of primitive types). In Swift, `struct` and `class` are *not* just syntactic sugar for a dictionary.  They are more like C-style `struct` - a bundle of binary data with a specific memory layout determined by the type.  In order to decode properly, `decode` has to know what it's decoding, and most often, how to tell that thing to decode itself via its `init(from: Decoder) throws` method (which may have been synthesized by the compiler).  Does it call `NSImage.init(from: Decoder)`, or `String.init(from: Decoder)`, etc... ?

If you're familiar with the way run-time polymorphism is implemented in OOP, providing the type, even generically, provides a means of obtaining the type's protocol witness table - which is sort of the protocol equivalent of the "vtable" that classes use for runtime dynamic dispatch for virtual methods. So it let's it do something analogous to calling a virtual method in OOP, except often it can figure it out at compile-time, and it can work for both value types and reference types.  Understanding how his works also gives some insight into different but related issues like why you get different polymorphic behavior for the required methods declared directly in a protocol than for those declared only in a protocol extension (basically the ones declared in the protocol directly are in the witness table, so they can be dynamically dispatched, whereas the ones only in the extension aren't in the witness table, so any type-specific implementations are lost, and instead only the implementation in the protocol's extension can be called).

The following function uses this to print the type of its parameter (there are better ways of doing this, but this illustrates the roles of `T.Type` and `T.self`):

```swift
func foo<T>(_ value: T)
{
    let typeOfValue: T.Type = T.self
    print("The value, \(value), is of type, \(typeOfValue).")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation

var landMarks: [Landmark] = load("landmarkData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T { 
...
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) 
...
}
```

you missing `var landMarks: [Landmark] = load("landmarkData.json")` this code, because the `func load(_:)->T` return value type is [Landmark] type ,so the T is [Landmark] Array type.

this is my understand